# Missing constraint

Tags: graph-theory, convex-cone

While reading [this](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/101356/CzechMathJ_25-1975-4_11.pdf) paper, I stumbled over the statement (1, 8) about linear independence in trees.

Just to make sure, that I understand it correctly: He means conical independence and forces $a_{i, k} \geq 0$?.

Linear independence as soon as the number of vertices $n$ is larger than the dimension should be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is linear independence.

A tree always has $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges, so here we are talking about the linear independence of $n-1$ elements of an $n$-dimensional space. This should always be possible; there is no dimension argument against it.

---

Another way to phrase the argument for proving this linear independence is by induction on the size of the tree. Suppose we have an $n$-vertex tree and vertex $s$ is a leaf with neighbor $t$. Then if
$$
   \sum_{vw \in E(T), v<w} a_{vw}(x_v - x_w) = 0
$$
the coefficient of $x_s$ is $a_{st}$ alone, so $a_{st} = 0$. Therefore
$$
   \sum_{vw \in E(T - s), v<w} a_{vw} (x_v - x_w) = 0
$$
and we have reduced the problem to one about the $(n-1)$-vertex tree $T-s$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Apparently I don't understand the meaning of the $x_i$. I thought they come from an embedding of the graph into a vector space. (The chemists in me thinks atoms = nodes and edges = bonds. ;-) )

Comment: $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ are the basis elements of the vector space.

Comment: So I have $n$ vertices and take a $n$ dimensional vector space. The $n$ basis elements are arbitrarily assigned to the $n$ vertices. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. (The vertices are named $1, 2, \dots, n$ and the basis elements $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, so there is a correspondence, which we make use of when we take the form $x_i - x_j$ for edge $ij$.)